# What does Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, sendmail

I am using sendmail to send mail from my Rails application. But, there seems to be a error happening while sending mails to a specific user domain. The error from `/var/mail/***` is as follows:

```
Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <MAILER-DAEMON@*****>
Message-Id: <201110111633.p9BGXkpR010310@******>
To: <****@*****>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
        boundary="p9BGXkpR010310.1318350826/******"
Subject: Returned mail: see transcript for details
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated (failure)
This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--p9BGXkpR010310.1318350826/*******

The original message was received at Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:42 GMT
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<****@{domain}.com>
    (reason: 573 ********@****** failed to route the address)
<*****@{domain}.com>
    (reason: 573 *******@****** failed to route the address)
<*****@{domain}.com>
    (reason: 573 *******@******* failed to route the address)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to *********.com.1.0001.arsmtp.com.:
>>> MAIL From:<*******@*******> SIZE=1273
<<< 573 ********@********* failed to route the address
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--p9BGXkpR010310.1318350826/*******
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; StreetSense
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost
Arrival-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:42 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; ****@*******.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 *******@******* failed to route the address
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; *******@********.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 *******@******** failed to route the address
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; ******@*********.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 573 *****@******** failed to route the address
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:33:46 GMT
```

The bounced back emails are all from the same domain, and mails are being successfully sent to other domains. When I looked for SMTP 573 diagnostic codes, I got this `"573 Internal server error, IP address related."`. But I dont know what it means. Can anyone help me?

**Update**

From @guenter's answer, I got these commands and I run it and got the following outputs:

```
# dig streetsense.com MX

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5 <<>> xxxxx.com MX
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61139
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xxxxx.com.     IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xxxxx.com.  3600    IN  MX  10 xxxxx.com.1.0001.arsmtp.com.
xxxxxx.com. 3600    IN  MX  20 xxxxx.com.2.0001.arsmtp.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns04.ntiva.net.
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns01.ntiva.net.
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns02.ntiva.net.
xxxxx.com.  155394  IN  NS  ns03.ntiva.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns01.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx
ns02.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx
ns03.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx
ns04.ntiva.net.     147 IN  A   xxx.xx.xx.xxx

;; Query time: 45 msec
;; SERVER: xxx.xxx.x.x#xx(xxx.xxx.x.x)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 11 18:08:23 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 262
```

ping also seem to be working:

```
# ping xxxxxxx.com
PING xxxxxxxx.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx) xx(xx) bytes of data.
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=29.0 ms
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from linux06.ntiva.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=27.4 ms
```

**Edit**

also my hostname of my server seems to be same as the domain name causing issue

```
# hostname
xxxxxxx
```

This is same as the domain `xxxxxxx.com`. Can this cause the issue?

Comment: I ended up using gmail SMTP for sending the mails. couldnt resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`failed to route the address` is the key here.

Seems that your `sendmail` doesn't know how to route that address. You need some mail-debugging here. First step could be to check the DNS for MX-records for this domain - `dig example.com MX`.

If there is no MX record, that is the problem. If there are MX record(s), you might try to ping that hosts.